# Spring Security asks for username and password despite patterns defined

Tags: java, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a problem with Spring Security Basic Auth. It still prompts for username and password, despite defining the patterns (or exceptions inside the url, I don't know the exact name).

I tried the following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        (authz) ->
                                authz
                        .requestMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .httpBasic(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

and I expect this to show me a simple index.html defined in resources/static folder.

Instead it still prompts for username and password.

Here is pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: i recommend you use spring security form login and not basic https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html

Answer (score -1):

index.html does not match any of
.requestMatchers("/", "index", "/css/*", "/js/*").permitAll() patterns

Also be sure that your authorized urls does not need ressources that require authentication
For example, in your case, any reference to an image will make the browser prompt for login / password :  since /img/** or any folder that contains images is not public

Answer (score -1):

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/", "/index", "/css/**", "/js/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .httpBasic()
            .disable();

    return http.build();
}
```

Please try it with this one.